# Strange highlighting behaviour?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I saw this question in the "New Questions" list, and for some reason it appears to be shaded out?

[image: Odd shading on new question]

I have selected the questions tagged [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), and I had a look at the revision history, no new tags were added, just the title was edited. I refreshed the page and it still appears this way.

Does anyone know the cause of this?

Answer (score 3):

Found it - I had a look on my profile and this is because I had a apparently added [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) to my "Ignored tags" list. With the "Grayed Out" behaviour.

[image: Ignored tag sql]